# how can i change color buttons on click ionic 2 angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I tried to change the color of the button i click, but it change all the colors of the buttons of the list

this is my code :

```js
ecardGroup(groupe) {
    if(this.hexColor === '#000000') { 
      this.hexColor = '#dddddd'
    } else {
      this.hexColor = '#000000'
    }
 }
```

```html
 <ion-col col-9 class="sildes">
                    <ion-slides slidesPerView="{{nbPerPage}}" spaceBetween="5">
                        <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of lesEboxs; let i = index">
                            <button ion-button block (click)="ecardGroup(slide)" class="currentGroup" [style.background-color]="hexColor">
                                <ion-icon class="warning"  name="star" *ngIf="slide.nom_gr == 'Pro'"></ion-icon>
                                {{slide.nom_gr}}
                            </button>
                        </ion-slide>
                    </ion-slides>
                </ion-col>
```

Comment: You set `background-color` to `hexColor` for all buttons. In your `ecardGroup(groupe)` function, you change the value of `hexColor` globally and not for specific button. Therefore, all buttons background-color will be concerned by this changement.

Comment: I first tried to change the color by using the id, but i only get undefined id, so i tried this method

Comment: Can you try this ? Create a slideClicked property on your class and change your template by :  `<button ion-button block [style.background-color]="(slide === this.slideClicked) ? '#000000' : '#dddddd'" (click)="this.slideClicked = slide" class="currentGroup">`

Comment: I wrote the solution, so if you could validate it, you will be the Angel King o/ @B.E2s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `slideClicked` property on your class and change your template like this :

`<button ion-button block [style.background-color]="(slide === this.slideClicked) ? '#000000' : '#dddddd'" (click)="this.slideClicked = slide" class="currentGroup">`